# CCK field outputs the value inside static html

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have a content type that i need to populate a pre-typed contract text

example: in the name field it will they will type their name and the output on the node will be

This contract is for "whatever-was-put-in-name-field" and blah blah blah because this is a contract.

i need this to be done for each field and if they don't type something in a field it doesn't show, just like how cck shows only the fields thats typed in or required.

Comment: If either of the suggested solutions worked, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Contemplate module. You can type out text and then just call token values for the CCK fields.

http://drupal.org/project/contemplate

Comment: but what about when a field isn't used? Can i make it so that it calls some text only when the field is used?

Comment: yes, like so: if(!empty($node->field_foo[0]['view'])){print whatever you want to print such as token values}

Answer (score 0):

Read how to create templates for [node types](http://drupal.org/node/17565) and [CCK fields](http://drupal.org/node/206980) and choose the way that fits your requirements.

Comment: is it a way for me to make text come only of a field is filled out?

Comment: could you give me a drupal example for a field and ill be set!

Comment: Copy the file `theme/content-field.tpl.php` from the CCK module in your theme directory. Clone the file in your theme directory. Name the clone `content-field-[name_of_your_field].tpl.php`. Edit this file as you like.